# IBM LDAP configuration issue

Tags: ldap, db2, openldap

I am doing IBM Tivoli LDAP installation on a CentOS 7 server. IBM DB2 is used for its database configuration. IBM DB2 is also installed on the same server. I am facing error in one step where we need to configure database for a directory server instance .

```
[root@dev02 sbin]# ./idscfgdb -I idsusr -a dasusr1 -w dasusr1 -l /home/idsusr -t ldapdb -n
GLPWRP123I The program '/opt/ibm/ldap/V6.3.1/sbin/64/idscfgdb' is used with the following arguments '-I idsusr -a dasusr1 -w ***** -l /home/idsusr -t ldapdb -n'.
You have chosen to perform the following actions:

GLPCDB023I Database 'ldapdb' will be configured.
GLPCDB024I Database 'ldapdb' will be created at '/home/idsusr'
GLPCDB035I Adding database 'ldapdb' to directory server instance: 'idsusr'.
GLPCTL017I Cataloging database instance node: 'idsusr'.
GLPCTL018I Cataloged database instance node: 'idsusr'.
GLPCTL008I Starting database manager for database instance: 'idsusr'.
GLPCTL009I Started database manager for database instance: 'idsusr'.
GLPCTL026I Creating database: 'ldapdb'.
GLPCTL028E Failed to create database: 'ldapdb'. The failure might have occurred because the system was not set up correctly before using the tool.
GLPCTL011I Stopping database manager for the database instance: 'idsusr'.
GLPCTL012I Stopped database manager for the database instance: 'idsusr'.
GLPCDB004E Failed to add database 'ldapdb' to directory server instance: 'idsusr'.
GLPCDB026W The program did not complete successfully. View earlier error messages for information about the exact error.
```

While checking the db logs , I found the following errors ----

> 2018-08-31-02.26.04.833398-240 E252943E465           LEVEL: Severe PID
>   : 31078                TID : 139826858813184 PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02 EDUID   : 14
>   EDUNAME: db2wlmt 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services,
>   sqloRequestSetPriority, probe:60 MESSAGE : ZRC=0xFFFFFBEE=-1042
>             SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
>
> DATA #1 : String, 29 bytes Unable to set thread priority
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.04.849838-240 I253409E533           LEVEL: Error (OS)
>   PID     : 31023                TID : 139826611349248 PROC : db2wdog 0
>   [idsusr] INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02
>   EDUID   : 2                    EDUNAME: db2wdog 0 [idsusr] FUNCTION:
>   DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloSetPriorityHdl, probe:5934 MESSAGE
>   : ZRC=0x83000001=-2097151999
>
> CALLED  : OS, -, sched_setscheduler               OSERR: EPERM (1)
>   DATA #1 : String, 51 bytes Failure setting absolute priority of kernel
>   thread.
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.04.853094-240 E253943E466           LEVEL: Severe PID
>   : 31078                TID : 139826854618880 PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02 EDUID   : 15
>   EDUNAME: db2wlmtm 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services,
>   sqloRequestSetPriority, probe:60 MESSAGE : ZRC=0xFFFFFBEE=-1042
>             SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
>
> DATA #1 : String, 29 bytes Unable to set thread priority
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.16.862999-240 E257903E347           LEVEL: Error (OS)
>   PID     : 31130                TID : 140560770324352 PROC : db2star2
>   INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02 FUNCTION:
>   DB2 UDB, SQO Memory Management, sqloMemCreateSingleSegment, probe:100
>   CALLED  : OS, -, shmget                           OSERR: EEXIST (17)
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.18.002541-240 E258251E726           LEVEL: Error (OS)
>   PID     : 31131                TID : 140560770324352 PROC : db2star2
>   INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02 FUNCTION:
>   DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloexecs, probe:2222 MESSAGE :
>   ZRC=0x8300000D=-2097151987
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.18.043809-240 I258978E433           LEVEL: Severe PID
>   : 31130                TID : 140560770324352 PROC : db2star2 INSTANCE:
>   idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB,
>   base sys utilities, sqleAdjustSharedMemoryLimits, probe:20 MESSAGE :
>   ZRC=0x840F0001=-2079391743=SQLO_ACCD "Access Denied"
>             DIA8701C Access denied for resource "", operating system return code
>             was "".
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.18.050443-240 E259412E347           LEVEL: Error (OS)
>   PID     : 31130                TID : 140560770324352 PROC : db2star2
>   INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 HOSTNAME: dev02 FUNCTION:
>   DB2 UDB, SQO Memory Management, sqloMemCreateSingleSegment, probe:100
>   CALLED  : OS, -, shmget                           OSERR: EEXIST (17)
>
> 2018-08-31-02.26.18.340053-240 I260908E491           LEVEL: Warning
>   PID     : 31078                TID : 139826829453056 PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: idsusr               NODE : 000 APPHDL  : 0-7
>   APPID: *LOCAL.idsusr.180831062618 HOSTNAME: dev02 EDUID   : 21
>   EDUNAME: db2agent (instance) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, bsu security,
>   sqlexLogPluginMessage, probe:20 DATA #1 : String with size, 66 bytes
>   Password validation for user dasusr1 failed with rc = -2146498587

At present , I am not able to understand for what issue is this step failing ? Is it some kernel error or is it some password validation issue ? I had made the password of dasusr1 same as dasusr1 so that it can be easily remembered and no issue comes . Can anybody guide me on this ?

Comment: Missing facts: (1) Db2 version, fixpack. (2) output of hostnamectl or `rpm --query centos-release` full release detail of centos . Edit your question to add the output of the command `db2level` which is located in the Db2 installation directory (and is runnable if su/sudo to the instance owner).  I believe IBM does not support Db2 on Centos officially, although it runs ok when properly configured.

Comment: Another thing to try is to su to idsusr account, then run command db2sampl.  That is a standalone tool to create a local database called SAMPLE.  If that also fails, your issue is with Db2 alone so it becomes essential to know the version+fixpack (db2level output). If db2sampl *succeeds*, your issue may be in IDS but there may be workarounds.

Comment: DB2 version is 10.1.0.0 . Output of 'rpm --query centos-release'  is 'centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64' . Output of db2level is $ db2level
DB21085I  Instance "idsusr" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10010" with
level identifier "0201010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.0", "s120403", "LINUXAMD64101", and Fix
Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1".

Comment: Also , I tried db2sampl from idsusr user ..... command ran successfully and SAMPLE database created .

Comment: Db2 V10.1 formally supported RHEL 5.6, but not later versions. So it would be a surprise if it had no issues on equivalent of RHEL 7.5.   You are wasting your time trying fixpack-0 of V10.1 (the final fixpack for that build is Fixpack 6).   Consider getting sign-off from your business for running unsupportable software. Alternatively consider *upgrading* your IDS product to currently supported levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script indicates that you are using dasusr1 (DB2 administration server user) while invoking idscfgdb. Documentation indicates database administrator ID should be used. Database administrator is different from DB2 administration server user. If you do not have separate user id for database administrator, you might be able to use instance owner id instead of database administrator.

Comment: Thank you very much Satya ...... Your solution worked ..... I used the idsusr ..... but I did one more thing prior to that ..... I changed the permissions for db2chpw
db2ckpw ..... I set it to -r-s--x--x ...... Unless these permissions are not changed , things wont work .